# Jquery sliding brands on click

Tags: jquery, html, sliding

I would like to use a jQuery effect from ASOS - 
http://www.asos.com/Men/A-To-Z-Of-Brands/Cat/pgehtml.aspx?cid=1361#

The nice thing is when you click a letter it slides to the specific row

The problem is there is a character limit in the CMS database of my site therefore the tables used in ASOS are too bulky to use.
Do you have any idea of a way round this with divs?

Comment: If you could edit your code down to just the essentials and properly tab it over for stackoverflow, it would help.  Also the question is not entirely clear.

Comment: Thanks Caimen, Sorry Its really difficult to decribe the function so I've just pasted in a link to Asos where i tried to take the code from. Thanks Judi

Comment: *I thought why rebuild Rome when its already built for you!* ...how about because *there is a character limit in the cms database of the site therefore these tables don't work* and, also, because you *know [you] shouldn't use tables*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` methods to simulate this sliding.

Say the table is at 'a' and you want to slide to 'c', you can use jQuery to slideUp 'a' and once that's done use jQuery again to slideUp 'b'. You'll have to specify this using the callback function for `slideUp()`. The same thing applies for reshowing elements (i.e you're going from 'c' to 'a'), except you use `slideDown()` to unhide your elements. Here's some code I wrote as an example:

```
function hideRecur(startLetterEl, stopLetterEl){
    if( startLetterEl === stopLetterEl ){
        return;
    }
    $(startLetterEl).slideUp("slow", 
        function(){ 
            var nextEl = $(startLetterEl).next()[0];
            if( nextEl){
                hideRecur(nextEl, stopLetterEl);
            }
        }
    );
}
function showRecur(startLetterEl, stopLetterEl){
    if( startLetterEl === stopLetterEl ){
        return;
    }
    $(startLetterEl).slideDown("slow", 
        function(){ 
            var prevEl = $(startLetterEl).prev()[0];
            if( prevEl){
                showRecur(prevEl, stopLetterEl);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/gitah/pUHAC/)

Comment: Thanks fsong, Thats fantastic. It works really well. I'm a bit of a novice at jquery. It only goes to E when I put the full alphabet in. Is there a way to set it for all the letters? Also if I all a show all link is there a way for it to go back to A? Thanks so much. Judi

Comment: Opps my mistake forgot to put the id in too, thats why it just went to E. :)